# how to handle sqlplus error in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am new to batch scripting..
I have test.bat batch file in which I am connecting to the different databases. But if ERROR: ORA-12154 or any connection error occurs it display message on command prompt, I want to display it into the result.txt file. I tried ERRORLEVEL but it always shows same ERRORLEVEL here is my test.bat :-

```
@ECHO On
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "delims== tokens=1,2" %%a in (D:\batch\InstallList.txt) do (
sqlplus %%b @D:\batch\mysql.sql
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 ECHO CONNECTION ERROR IN %%a >> D:\batch\\result.txt
) 
pause;
```

but its not working; ERRORLEVEL remains same for all databases.
In InstallList.txt

```
db1=username/password
db2=username/password
db3=username/password
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try next approach with [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "delims== tokens=1,2" %%a in (D:\batch\InstallList.txt) do (
    sqlplus %%b @D:\batch\mysql.sql 2>>  D:\batch\result.txt
    set "xERROR=!ERRORLEVEL!"
    echo %%a !xERROR!
    if !xERROR! NEQ 0 (
        ECHO CONNECTION ERROR !xERROR! IN %%a >> D:\batch\result.txt
    ) else (
        ECHO CONNECTED WITH NO ERROR ^(!xERROR!^) IN %%a >> D:\batch\result.txt
    )
) 
pause
```

Explanation:

- use `!ERRORLEVEL!` instead of `%ERRORLEVEL%` to force expanding `ERRORLEVEL` variable at execution time rather than at parse time: normally an entire `FOR` loop is evaluated as a single command even if it spans multiple lines of a batch script;
- **edit** add unconditional `echo %%a !xERROR!` to see which `ERRORLEVEL` raised factually;
- **edit** add `ELSE` and log result in both cases;
- use `!xERROR! NEQ 0` condition rather than `!xERROR! EQU 0` as  in general a code of `0` (false) will indicate [successful completion](http://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html);
- **edit2** `sqlplus %%b @D:\batch\mysql.sql 2>> D:\batch\result.txt`  should append any `sqlplus` error message(s) into the log file. Here `2` in `2>>` is a [standard error text output handle](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html).

Comment: thanks josef but its not working it always print message in result.txt, even if there is error in connection

Comment: sorry, i wanted to say even if there is "no" error in connection.

Comment: Can we add errorcode along with message like error due to errorcode ORA-12154